# Local fonts fails to resolve in next.js while deploying in vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fonts, vercel

I am trying to use `next/fonts` in `next.js 13.3`. Everything works fine locally but when I deployed to Vercel, I keep getting this build error `Module not found: Can't resolve './fonts/BrFirma-Thin.woff2'`

This is what my folder structure looks like

- src

  - _app.js
  - styles

    - font.js
    - fonts

`_app.js`

```
import { BRFirma } from 'styles/font';
...
 <main className={BRFirma.className}>
  ...
 </main>
```

`font.js`

```
import localFont from 'next/font/local';

export const BRFirma = localFont({
    src: [
       
        {
            path: './fonts/BrFirma-Regular.woff2',
            weight: '400',
        },
        {
            path: './fonts/BrFirma-SemiBold.woff2',
            weight: '600',
        },
    ],
});
```

Again I moved the fonts to the public folder just to make sure I am doing it right.

`font.js`

```
import localFont from 'next/font/local';

export const BRFirma = localFont({
    src: [
       
        {
            path: '../../public/assets/fonts/BrFirma-Regular.woff2',
            weight: '400',
        },
        {
            path: '../../public/assets/fonts/BrFirma-SemiBold.woff2',
            weight: '600',
        },
    ],
});
```

Once again, everything works fine locally but deployment still fails with the `module not found` message.

Just for the record, this is what `jsconfig.js` file looks like.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist", "jest"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue today, not really sure why vercel doesn't like some fonts but try downloading the font file from a different place. the path you're using is not the problem. https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2367

Comment: Thanks, I resolved to use the CSS way already, I will try this next time.